# Visual Studio - References automatically update

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, reference

I have an MVC project (Project A) within a larger solution, and another MVC project (Project B) in a separate solution. Project B references the Project A .dll within Project A's bin folder.

When I make changes to project A which need to be referenced in project B, do I have to unload and reload the reference, or can I only copy the reference at compile time and it will grab the latest version from Project A's bin folder?

In short, is it necessary to delete and re-add a reference when it changes (even if it's in the same location) and can it be done automatically?

JK

Comment: _"Project B references the Project A .dll within Project A's bin folder."_ - don't do that. Use a Project Reference, or build the referenced project automatically and reference the output assembly. Never reference assemblies from another project's bin folder. And no, you don't need to update references.

Comment: Can you explain why? And you're saying that on Project A being recompiled Project B's reference to it will remain up-to-date?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still curious as to why exactly this is bad practice....But anyway... So if the projects are in different solutions can you explain exactly how I should reference to achieve the synchronisation I want? I'm am not familiar with how to build the referenced project as a pre-requisite for a project in a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just add Project A to solution of Project B ?
When Project B reference a project A, a dependency exist and MsBuild will build the Project A before B. When you reference a library, msbuild do noting, just use the dependancy to build. Good practice is to reference libraries for external dependancies and projects for our "own" code.

Comment: I have done this now. I was just curious as to exactly what the options were for this. Thanks for the explanation.